# Java EE periodic database query

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-5

I'm working on a JavaEE 5 application, and I need to create a task that will periodically query the database for some information, and then make the result available to a jsp page.

The result is the same for all page requests, it just needs to be periodically updated. A given result should be available to web components until the next update is ready. If no result is available when a page is requested is simply won't display it (the page doesn't wait for the result). So I have one producer that queries the database and multiple consumers, that just check if a result is available and move on if it's not.

In a Java SE environment, I would just create a new thread and place the result in a shared thread-safe object, but I read that it's not a good idea to manually spawn threads in a Java EE container.

So my questions are:

1. How do I schedule a bean to do a database query at every x minutes? Is Timer Service a good solution for JavaEE 5?
2. What is the best way to share the result of a query result with web components? Should I just place them in the servlet context? Can the enterprise bean even write to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well you requirement, but is a very bad idea to query periodically, just to refresh the web page with fresh information, this will kill your application performance, and store this in the servlet context is even worst.
What you could do, is dispatch events, when one entity is created/updated, and that change you query, then you could add this information in the page using websockets without even refresh the page and with thousands more performance factor, this could be done with all clients that are connected and even filtered by clients that are in the same topic.

Or you could use an ajax to periodic check if the information change, and only fetch that information when needed, this do not scale as a websocket but is a better alternative if you can't use.

But I have experience with Java EE 6, with 5 I don't think you have CDI Events And Interceptors but you could use the observer pattern, is simply to implement. CDI Interceptor is very useful in this case because you can intercept the event in a central way and then process that information and send to clients using whatever technology, in this case websocket fits the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a job scheduler like Quartz http://quartz-scheduler.org/ and embed it into your jsp or servlet.

[Quartz Scheduler in servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563212/quartz-scheduler-in-servlets)

http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-job-scheduling-in-web-application-with-quartz-api/